# Libvirt: Can't shutdown or reboot virtual guest

Tags: kvm-virtualization, centos6, libvirt

I can't reboot or shutdown the guest vm from the host machine

```
virsh -c qemu:///system reboot vm1
Domain vm1 is being rebooted
```

After executing this, nothing happens. The guest vm keeps working.

Could anyone help? I'm using CentOS 6.3, libvirtd, kvm. The guest vm is also CentOS 6.3

Comment: I'm seeing lots of messages on old forums and mailing lists that this has something to do with ACPI. I have it enabled both on host and guest vm. Is there anything else I can check?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This command sends an ACPI shutdown to the guest. If the guest cannot understand those, nothing will happen.

Make sure you have acpid working in the guest. You can set up acpid in your guest with commands like this:

```
yum install acpid
chkconfig acpid on
service acpid start
```

Once acpid is installed, you should be able to use virsh or other libvirt-compatible tools to shutdown or reboot your guest.